# C# check merge field check box in a word document

Tags: .net

Just wondering how to check a check box on a word document, i have my C# Window Forms application filling in Merge Fields with data obtained from the forms such as textBoxes and comboBoxes. Though i was wondering how to check a text box from with in C#?

I have been trying to find this for awhile now, and have resulted in actually asking the question here.

The code below is how i connect to my word document and fill out the Merge Field on that document.

```
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Object oTrue = true;
        Object oFalse = false;
        Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();

        oWord.Visible = true;

        if (File.Exists("pathName.txt"))
        {
            FileStream file = new FileStream("pathName.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(file);
            PathName = Reader.ReadLine();
        }

        Object oTemplatePath = PathName;

        oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        foreach (Word.Field myMergeField in oWordDoc.Fields)
        {
            iTotalFields++;
            Word.Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
            String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;

            if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
            {

                Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
                Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
                String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);

                fieldName = fieldName.Trim();



                if (fieldName == "Name")
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(firstName.Text);
                }

                if (fieldName == "Name2")
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(textBox6.Text);
                }

                if (fieldName == "LastName1")
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(textBox3.Text);
                }
       }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Show your own work (i.e. code) first before someone could help you.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited my code in.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated!!!! :(